# JAXB wrap non-collection fields

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Given a xml file where each value is wrapped in it's own element like that:

```
<root>
    <type1>
        <foo>1</foo>
    </type1>
    <type2>
        <bar>2</bar>
    </type2>
</root>
```

is there some easy way to map this? Like `@XmlElement("type1/foo")` or `@XmlElementWrapper("type1") @XmlElement("foo")`? As far as I can tell I need to create a corresponding class model (`Root`, `Type1`, `Type2`) where `Type1` and `Type2` provide no added value but only act as a wrapper.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for something like this in my application as well. I need to use the wrapper element for non-collection. Did you find the answer to this? If so can you please guide me through it?